# Google Container Engine doesn't support XFS by default

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Any way around this. Trying to mount an XFS disk.

> safe_format_and_mount: Running: mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-storage-disk /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/storage-disk
>
> safe_format_and_mount: mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Answer (score 0):

The default GKE nodes do not have XFS tools installed, though they do have the kernel module.  If you manually install xfsprogs it should work, though it's probably not samething we'll install by default (trying to keep it very small)